# How to write Web API call in AngularJS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web API that is working from the address line of my browser, but when I try to write AngularJS or jQuery calls they fail with no explanation.  I think I don't have the correct route in the URL, or maybe it's a JSON formatting problem.  I had an earlier version of the Web API and the same calls from AngularJS or jQuery worked.  But in that earlier version I had declared the action in the route.  Then I read in a RESTful Web API it's best practice to omit the action in the route and base the route off the HTTP method.  So I rebuilt the Web API to do it that way, but now I can't reconnect on the client side.  Can someone see the error in my URL route?  You can test the URL in this example and see the data in your browser.

Note: I think I have solved this problem.  I need to add a JSON formatter in my new Web API.  It was in my first version.  That is the only difference I have found so far.

```html
            var sURL2 = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Securities?SecurityType=CASH";
            $http.get(sURL2)
                .then(function (oData)
                {
                    alert("oData = " + oData);
                    $scope.Securities = oData;
                }, function (response)
                {
                    alert("error = " + response.statusText);
                });
```

Comment: i think what $http should send a object, i always use $http like a : var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'your url'
};
$http(req).then( function successCallback(successData){},
function(errorCallback(errorData){});  hm, show source-cod of your controller and model. and yes, check json formatter.

Comment: Just add your endpoint api adress to the $http.get() and not the whole url, use: var sURL2 = "api/Securities?SecurityType=CASH";

Comment: what is the route defined in the routeconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work.  I think the problem lay in the client javascript, but I also re-wrote the Web API, so I'm not sure.  One thing I know changed in the javascript was I had used the jQuery .success method, but I changed it to .then because of jQuery deprecating .success.  When I did that I had to use the data property of the dataResponse.  Just plain dataResponse won't work.  I guess it's a different type of object.

```html
            $http.get(sURL2)
                .then(function (dataResponse)
                {
                    // this doesn't work
                    // $scope.Securities = dataResponse.data.records;
                    // this doesn't work
                    // $scope.Securities = dataResponse;

                    // this works
                    $scope.Securities = dataResponse.data;
                }, function (response)
                {
                    alert("error = " + response.statusText);
                });
```